# NSCollectionView performBatchUpdates doesn't animate changes

Tags: swift, cocoa

When I do the animations individually everything works fine, but inside of a `performBatchUpdates` block the change is instant, almost like I called `reloadData()`. Am I using it correctly?

**Working method:**

```
NSAnimationContext.currentContext().duration = 0.25

indexPathChanges.map({collectionView.animator().moveItemAtIndexPath($0.0, toIndexPath: $0.1)})
```

**`performBatchUpdates` version (instant change - no animation):**

```
NSAnimationContext.currentContext().duration = 0.25

collectionView.performBatchUpdates(  {
    indexPathChanges.map({self.collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath($0.0, toIndexPath: $0.1)})

    // tried this as well - no luck    
    // indexPathChanges.map({self.collectionView.animator().moveItemAtIndexPath($0.0, toIndexPath: $0.1)})

}, completionHandler: {(finished) in print("Finished: \(finished)")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to put it this way:

```
collectionView.animator().performBatchUpdates({<your animations>}, completionHandler:{finished in <your completion handler>})
```

In other words, pass it through `animator()` proxy.

Comment: I'm finding that, although this works, I get some annoying unwanted animations if I make more than one type of change and use a custom layout with custom animations.

Comment: Value of type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'animator'

Comment: The question and answer is about `NSCollectionView`, not `UICollectionView`.